# Get best result model only from auto.arima

Tags: r, time-series, arima

After executing an `auto.arima` proccess like this:

`result <- auto.arima(timeSerie)`

How can I get from result the best model selected by `auto.arima`?

For example, I ger the BIC: `result$bic`, but I'm lost getting (1,1,0) in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(forecast)
result <- auto.arima(WWWusage)
result
#> Series: WWWusage 
#> ARIMA(1,1,1) 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>          ar1     ma1
#>       0.6504  0.5256
#> s.e.  0.0842  0.0896
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 9.995:  log likelihood=-254.15
#> AIC=514.3   AICc=514.55   BIC=522.08
as.character(result)
#> [1] "ARIMA(1,1,1)"
arimaorder(result)
#> p d q 
#> 1 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>